# Visual Basic Designer- Make border size relative to popup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, border, designer

I am working with C# in Visual Studio in .designer.cs. How can I make the groupboarder's size relative to my popup? eg. when I drag my popup to be bigger, the border increases with it.

Answer (score 0):

Set GroupBox's [Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) property to ensure that the GroupBox's edges remain in the same position relative to the edges of the parent (popup). Default is **Top** and **Left**